# Is there anything short I can read on the difference between learning something as an adult vs as a child?

Tags: learning

Is there anything short I can read on the difference between learning something as an adult vs as a child?

Learning a language, or mathematics, or facts, whatever.

Comment: To be (too) personal: I find that I learn things a lot, lot slower now. Not just 'languages' but, as I child, I would usually only have to read and not do exercises for things to "stick". Now, as an adult, it seems to have to do exercises immediately after learning something new, and then do them again, and again to make it "stick". I'm somewhat concerned if this is normal!

Comment: I am voting to close this question because [questions regarding book recommendations are off-topic here](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/943)